# MaxConnectionsPerHost vs MaxRequestsPerConnection Cassandra driver

Tags: java, performance, cassandra, bigdata, datastax-java-driver

I'm working with huge query set for C*. I already throttle async query executor with

```
Semaphore maxInFlight = new Semaphore(MAX_REQUEST_PER_CON_REMOTE);
...
maxInFlight.acquireUninterruptibly();
ResultSetFuture future = executeAsync(...);
Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(ResultSet rs) {
     ...
     maxInFlight.release();
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
     ...
     maxInFlight.release();
     }, executor);
```

where *MAX_REQUEST_PER_CON_REMOTE* is  MaxRequestsPerConnection parameter.
MaxConnectionsPerHos equals 1 by default and I didn't change it.

With increasing the number of nodes or increasing replication factor, i believe, that I could increase MaxConnectionsPerHos or MaxRequestsPerConnection to increase productivity.
Is there any advantages increasing one or another?

Also then I want change dependency of Semaphore permits, but don't actually know how. The idea is to add listener and updating maxInFlight when Host was added or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using Whitelist or Blacklist policy, then driver will connect to the every host separately (depending of course on configuration, if you're using DC Aware policy). So when you add the new node, then driver will add a new connection to that node, and load will be redistributed (if your queries don't have "hot" partitions). If you increase replication factor, then it also doesn't matter much, because sending requests to replicas will be done not by driver, but by the "coordinator" node...

So when you have N nodes in local DC, then you theoretically can send up to the `N * MaxInFlighConnections` requests (but this depends on the distribution of data in your requests).

Also, I see that you're using `MAX_REQUEST_PER_CON_REMOTE` - it's better to send requests only to nodes to local DC. Also you can configure up to 32k requests per connection, and in the most cases this is more than enough for one client doing the requests.

You can find more information in [Driver's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/pooling/).

P.S. I have a [separate class](https://github.com/alexott/datastax-bootcamp-project/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/bootcamp/SessionLimiter.java) that uses the same approach with Semaphore, but adds listener automatically - feel free to grab it.

Comment: Hi, Alex. Thanks for your answer.
In your code on github I see, that you limit the number of request by constant too, but, for example, if one host went down or maybe new host was added it doesn't change. I believe there is a way to make it change dynamically, depending on number of active hosts or response time or smth else. But actually, I just don't know does it improve performance or not.

Comment: It's really a bigger problem to do this automatically, as we need to limit the number of requests per connection to particular host, and this depend on the data distribution in your cluster, and your queries - it could be that some partition range will get more requests than other. In this case, having global limit will cause BusyPoolException as well... I talked with developers about it - they *may* implement something more sophisticated than my code in the next major release of Java driver